# Is there a way to open an SP2019 document in office online or in the browser?

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, office-365

I have a document in SP2019 uploaded in a library. Unfortunately, when I select it and click "open in word online" a blank page opens and the document is downloaded on my computer.

I was wondering if there was a way for me, using javascript, a webpart or something else, to open it and / or modify it in the browser.

I gathered that there is a way to view a document in office online using "https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc". Unfortunately, when I try with the URL of my SP2019 document, I get an error page.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can do this ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need [Office Online Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/officeonlineserver/office-online-server) deployed into your environment.

This must be installed on a separate server with no other services but it will allow you to view and edit various modern Office file types within the browser.

Note that you do need Office licensing for your users to use OOS (it's licensed via Office client...) and you cannot run it in a shared hosting environment, i.e., Azure, AWS, or GCP VMs due to licensing, again.